# Remote Procedure Call - Service offered by client

Tags: c++, qt, rpc, grpc

I want to develop a Qt5/C++ client-server application using remote procedure calls (RPC).

Idea:
The server listens for incoming connections of multiple clients.
Clients offer a set of procedures/services the server can call in order to collect data from clients and inform other clients about changes.

And here is the catch:
The RPC libs i've seen so far seem to expect the server to offer a service the clients may call. But I want to do the opposite. Clients should offer services the server may call.
<s>The direction is important, because I want to enable port forwarding on the server side only, not on the client side.</s>

The libs I've checked are:

- QtRpc2 (https://github.com/brendan0powers/QtRpc2)
- grpc (http://www.grpc.io)

Questions:

- Is there a reason these libs offer services on server side only?
- Did I maybe only miss that part in the documentation?
- Is there an RPC lib that does offer client side service offering?

Comment: Please confirm: It sounds like you want A connects to B and offers services to B.

Comment: Yes, thats how it's supposed to work.

Comment: Don't know of any off hand. Have you considered A opens tunnel to B, B connects to and requests services from A through the tunnel?

Comment: You have asked 3 questions about libraries you look in and we can mostly answer in terms of tags: C++ / Qt / RPC. That makes us study those 3rd party libraries? I can probably offer you something how to work around such  demand but the 3 questions aren't about that.

Comment: I don't expect anyone to study libraries for me :) Maybe someone has already had experience with a lib and found a way to offer services on client side.

I would really like to know your workarounds for my problem.

Comment: If found this answer to related question:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/30009838/7401546

"No, a server cannot invoke calls on the client. gRPC works with HTTP, and HTTP has not had such semantics in the past."

Comment: Look at Qt Websockets: server requests client via websocket and the client replies via HTTP/REST. I can explain in more details and refer to docs but unsure whether you want it or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gRPC supports bidirectional streaming, which may meet your needs.

Clients can open a long lived connection to a server, and then the server can "call" the clients by sending responses on the stream.

The client can respond by sending another message on the stream.

http://www.grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/c.html